# CodeIgniter - How to check if there is anything in the validation_error array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm wanting to display a general error message if there are any errors in the `validation_errors()` array, but if I do something like

```
if(isset(validation_errors())) { echo 'error'; }
```

then it returns back and says:

> Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context

Any help would be grand.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if(validation_errors() != false) { echo 'error'; }
```

`isset` is used to Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 2):

Just `echo vadidation_errors()`

It will output if there are errors, and nothing if no errors. You don't need `if`

Comment: What if you want to contain the errors in a div. Not each individual divs, but a wrapping div.  In that case you need an if statement

Comment: @jsheffers You can specify the wrappers in the function params: `validation_errors('<div>', '</div>')`